# How to get MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON response using rest + jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, media-type

I'm trying to do a simple rest client but I'm stuck trying to call a method which has as return type "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON".

Basically I'm my java client I'm doing this:

```
private static String init(String password, String users) throws Exception  {
         Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); 
         WebTarget target = client.target(BASE_URI +MessageFormat.format("init/{0}/{1}", new Object[] {password,users}));

         return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
}
```

But I'm getting Error 404 when I'm doing the return

Comment: 404 suggests your URI is wrong.

Comment: Double check the requested URL.